# jQuery callback when ajax request is finished loading

Tags: jquery

In jQuery is there a callback that can be used when an ajax request is finished loading. The reason I am wondering is because I'd like to display a loading gif until the the ajax request is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) regarding ajax events. All you will need to do is bind to `ajaxComplete` and then you can clear you loading picture from there.

Comment: That page is probably a more thorough explanation as it includes the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you look at the jQuery documentation, there is a callback value you can set.

complete(jqXHR, textStatus) or maybe success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Just set a property named "success" or "complete" with a function you want called on your ajax setting object that you pass in on your ajax call and it should get invoked when the request is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>   A function to be
>   called if the request succeeds.

or

> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) A function to be called if the
>   request fails.

or even:

> complete(jqXHR, textStatus) A function to be called when the request
>   finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).